# Protobuf: repeated should emit set accessors

Tags: .net, protocol-buffers, grpc, protobuf-net, protobuf-csharp-port

.Net

The **protobuff compiler generates** a class in which **repeated fields** are **read-only**.

### How to make them { get; set; }?

Let's say I have this proto code:

```
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "gRPC";

service MyService{
    rpc Foo(Request) returns (Response);
}

message Response{
    repeated string value = 1;
}

message Request{
    string id = 1;
}
```

Protobuff compiler generates this:

```
public pbc::RepeatedField<string> Value {
      get { return value_; }
    }
```

How to make him generate something like this:

```
public pbc::RepeatedField<string> Value {
      get { return value_; }
      set {
        value_ = pb::ProtoPreconditions.CheckNotNull(value, "value");
      }
    }
```

Comment: Collections are already mutable; the idea is that you `.Add` etc your contents; why do you need to change the collection instance itself?

Comment: @MarcGravell Thank you for reply. You're right, I'm using `.Add()` but I've found it is possible to convert repeated fields with `set;` just I don't know how. In my case, this will simplify the code. And just out of curiosity :)